# CSS transform:rotate3d animate with perspective

Tags: css

I have a wheel I would like to rotate while keeping perspective.
The code below allows me to spin the wheel, but I cant keep an angled perspective

```
@keyframes mywheel {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

angled perspective:

```
@keyframes mywheel {
    from { transform:rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 65deg); }
    to { transform:rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 65deg); }
}
```

How can I combine the 2 and rotate the img while keeping a perspective?

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/emyL86p8/)

**fixed** this worked:

```
@keyframes mywheel {
    from { transform:rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 65deg); rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 65deg); rotate(-360deg);}
}
```